# Google Play Game Services - How to Not Leave Room onPause

Tags: android, multiplayer, google-play-games

I'm not sure why "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142763/is-it-possible-to-show-full-screen-activity-without-leaving-room-using-google-re" was closed as "off topic" as I have the same question.

If I switch to text messaging, someone calls, etc, then onPause() and potentially onStop() will be called. I presume those are what forces one to leave the room in a multiplayer game. I would rather the game not be ruined by these events though. Is it possible to somehow stay in the room while sending someone a quick text message or answering a phone call? Must I create a background service or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: It's not possible because of the way the API is designed. Bruno has explained that several times. If the API were designed to allow you to retain state, sure. But Google made the decision not to go in that direction.

I don't see that the question is off topic, but you ARE asking for something counter to the API. That's just the way it works, and there's not much use asking why it's not possible.

Comment: I asked "if" not "why" but I guess the answer is "no" if you are correct. That's rather unfortunate. So everyone has this issue then if you are playing a multiplayer game and someone calls you? You're simply out of the game? Pretty lame! Oh well...

Comment: It is unfortunate :-(

Comment: Yeah... right now, that's part of the API's design. There is no way around it. Also, please resist the temptation to avoid calling leaveRoom on onStop() hoping to continue a match, because that will cause resource leaks :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have edited BaseGameActivity.onStop() and have removed gamehelper.onStop().
So I stop gamesclient only in onDestroy.
My game work perfectly also in background now.

Comment: Hmm... It sounds good on the surface, but it is possible for OnDestroy to not be called even when destroyed. I wonder what the repercussions of that would be. Will it clean up after a while? Seems like it should. So this might be a good option.